# How to call Microsoft's dialog in VSIX custom wizard extensions?

Tags: uwp, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm developing Project templates for UWP. In default Microsoft's UWP templates, if we click create template, a dialog will be open to ask the target and minimum version of Windows.

[image]

I'm creating a custom wizard with custom window to get project configuration details. My goal is, if the user click the OK button of my custom window, the above default dialog should open and get the Target and minimum version from the user and create the project based on it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Im waitting for your VSIX.

Comment: @lindexi What it means?

Comment: I also want it.